# How to install Ubuntu 13.10 on Acer C7 Chromebook via USB?

Tags: system-installation, chromebook

I am using Chromebook Acer C7. Since the BIOS is EFI, how can I install Ubuntu 13.10 from USB on that laptop? Will Unetbootin work on that? As I went to that website it tells that it can't boot from Mac OS X devices, so I suppose it will not work on chromebooks. So if not then what tool will?

I heard that Ubuntu 13.10 will come with kernel 9.12 or something that which will support chromebook. But can I make bootable usb or will it download and install from net as 12.04 and 13.04 do directly? Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

Acer C7's stock firmware won't let you boot Ubuntu USB images.

I've had some success overwriting the stock firmware with coreboot / seabios by following instructions here: http://johnlewis.ie/pre-built-coreboot-firmware-for-chromebooks/ It's a warranty voiding procedure.

After that, it should boot any linux live CD, installer images from USB sticks. I've verified this with the Ubuntu default `usb-creator-gtk` and have detailed my experience here: https://askubuntu.com/a/361561/97517

Answer (score 0):

Try [ChrUbuntu](http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.com/) 12.04. It will give you a working system. As far as I know you can run a normal kernel on your device since it is recent, unlike the Samsung Series 5 or 550.

Answer (score 0):

ChrUbuntu 12.04 works well on the Acer C7. I have installed it and use it regularly.

Updates to 12.10 and 13.04 worked well. 13.10 I have an issue with hardware acceleration on the video card, but otherwise works well.